# GridBagLayout component placing

Tags: java, layout, gridbaglayout

1. I'm having a problem with this layout. How do I make the third button 2x2 in size with *gridwidth*?
2. I'm also wondering, if I'd like to stretch the second button to be two columns wide, how do I say where to start and where to stop? How to differentiate when it's covering columns 1 and 2 from the case when it's covering columns 2 and 3?

   ```
   public class SwingExample {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame theFrame = new JFrame("Grid Bag Example");
      theFrame.setSize(600,400);
      theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();
      theFrame.add(thePanel);  

      JButton button1 = new JButton("1");  
      JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
      JButton button3 = new JButton("3");

      GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();                                            
      thePanel.setLayout(gbl);
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;                
      thePanel.add(button1,gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 1;
      gbc.gridy = 1;    
      thePanel.add(button2,gbc);

      gbc.gridwidth = 2;
      gbc.gridheight = 2;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
      gbc.gridx = 3;
      gbc.gridy = 3;
      thePanel.add(button3,gbc);

      theFrame.setVisible(true);   
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: The gridwidth is relative to other components in those columns. you only have 3 columns. You can't just make the third button have a width of 2 because it is the only button in the third column. If you place the third button in column 0, then you can give it a width of two, because now it can occupy the width of the buttons in the first two columns.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that sentence - _gridwidth is relative to other components in those columns_. I don't understand that. [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#gridwidth) clearly says it _Specifies the number of cells in a row for the component's display area._ Seems very plain and straightforward.

Comment: You don't have a component in column 4, so you can't say the component in column 3 can span column 3 and 4. I gave you an example of how  a component can span multiple columns. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout[(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: I've read that tutorial 3 times. Nothing is explained there. It says that _gridwidth and gridheight specify the number of columns (for gridwidth) or rows (for gridheight) in the component's display area_, but they obviously don't, as can be seen when executing my code. Next,  I added button4 at position (4,4) nothing happens. It can't even be seen. I've tried adding it at position (5, 5) now all 4 buttons are present, but button3 is still NOT 2x2 and button4 is at position(4, 4) and it's not coded to be there. Is there any decent tutorial about this? This is just stupid behavior.

Comment: And what the heck would component in column 4, which I BTW don't want and need, have to do with behavior and spanning of component 3, which I'm trying to set according to Oracle suggestion with gridwidth and gridheight? Is there a trick with some dummy, invisible, zero-dimension component that I have to add behind the last component I want painted?

Answer (score 0):

First of all did you run the demo code in the tutorial???

I'll try to explain the tutorial code to give you a better understanding. It demonstrates how to use the `gridwidth` constraint such that:

1. the button on the second row spans 3 columns
2. the button on the third row spans 2 columns starting at the second column.

The GridBagLayout first needs to determine the width of each column that contains a component. So the largest component for each column is found.

Now that you know the size of the largest component in each column you can determine the size of the buttons in rows 2 and 3 by adding up the columns widths. The button in row 2 would add the width of all 3 columns. The button in column 3 would add the width of only the last two columns.

> And what the heck would component in column 4 have to do with behavior and spanning of component 3

If you want a component to span multiple columns, then some other row must have a component in that column so the width of the column can be determined. Just because you use a `gridwidth = 2` doesn't mean the button will automatically double in size.

> gbc.gridx = 3;

Above you can't just have button 3 magically show up in column 3. There are no components in column2 so the width of column 2 will be 0.

> Is there a trick with some dummy, invisible, zero-dimension component

Well you can't use a zero dimensional component because then the width/height would be zero which means the column/row size would also be zero. So you could add a dummy component with a size. For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   JFrame theFrame = new JFrame("Grid Bag Example");
   theFrame.setSize(600,400);
   theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();
   theFrame.add(thePanel);

   JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
   JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
   JButton button3 = new JButton("3");

   JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
   label1.setPreferredSize( button1.getPreferredSize() );
   JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
   label2.setPreferredSize( button1.getPreferredSize() );

   GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
   thePanel.setLayout(gbl);
   GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
   gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
   gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

   gbc.gridx = 0;
   gbc.gridy = 0;
   thePanel.add(button1,gbc);

   gbc.gridx = 1;
   gbc.gridy = 1;
   thePanel.add(button2,gbc);

   gbc.gridx = 2;
   gbc.gridy = 2;
   thePanel.add(label1,gbc); // dummy component

   gbc.gridx = 3;
   gbc.gridy = 3;
   thePanel.add(label2,gbc); // dummy component

   gbc.gridx = 2;
   gbc.gridy = 2;
   gbc.gridwidth = 2;
   gbc.gridheight = 2;
   thePanel.add(button3,gbc);

   theFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

In the above code comment out the adding of either label to the panel and you will see it stops working because there is no component that occupies the individual cell for the column/row. That is what I was trying to explain when I stated the gridwidth is relative to other components in the column.

Comment: So there is no actual grid here? I don't make any grid and then throw in components? There are only components added, and then I imagine they form a grid, and then try to manipulate them through imaginary grid?

Comment: You make the grid as big as you want by adding components to the grid. If you don't add a component to a cell in the grid then the size of that cell is (0, 0). I don't know how to explain it any better. The only way to understand is to play with the working examples you have been given, both in the tutorial link and the above code.

Comment: OK, will try. Thanks.